# I don't have the right outcome in pyomo model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

Oxbridge University maintains a powerful mainframe computer for research use by its faculty, Ph.D. students, and research associates. During all working hours, an operator must be available to operate and maintain the computer, as well as to perform some programming services. Beryl Ingram, the director of the computer facility, oversees the operation. It is now the beginning of the fall semester, and Beryl is confronted with the problem of assigning different working hours to her operators. Because all the operators are currently enrolled in the university, they are available to work only a limited number of hours each day. The table below shows, for each operator, both the wage per hour and the maximum number of working hours that the operator is available per week.

There are six operators (four undergraduate students and two graduate students). They all have different wage rates because of differences in their experience with computers and in their programming ability. Each operator is guaranteed a certain minimum number of hours per week that will maintain an adequate knowledge of the operation. This level is set at 8 hours per week for the undergraduate students (K.C., D.H., H.B., and S.C.) and 7 hours per week for the graduate students (K.S. and N.K.). The computer facility is to be open for operation from 8 AM to 10 PM Monday through Friday with exactly one operator on duty during each of these hours. Because of a tight budget, Beryl has to minimize cost. She wishes to determine the number of hours she should assign to each operator on each day. Formulate a linear programming model for this problem.

Write a function:

named model_oxbridge, with no arguments
returning a pyomo model
The model should have:
one indexed variable named x, stating the number of hours per day that each operator should be on duty.
Make sure that this variable is indexed first by the operator names (K.C., D.H., etc.), and then by the days (Mon, Tue, etc.). These names should be equal to the index- and column names in the data table as defined in the next cell.
three indexed constraints
min_hours: make sure each operator is working their minimal number of hours.
availability: make sure that on each day, each operator is not working more than their available number of hours.
day_total: make sure the total number of hours worked each day is exactly 14 hours (8 AM to 10 PM).
one objective, named wage.

[image: table]

**The outcome should be 1755, however I have 486**

```
# DO NOT CHANGE
import pyomo.environ as pyo
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO('''Operator;Wage;Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;MinHours
K.C.; 25 ; 6 ; 0 ; 6 ; 0 ; 6 ; 8
D.H.; 26 ; 0 ; 6 ; 0 ; 6 ; 0 ; 8
H.B.; 24 ; 4 ; 8 ; 4 ; 0 ; 4 ; 8
S.C.; 23 ; 5 ; 5 ; 5 ; 0 ; 5 ; 8
K.S.; 28 ; 3 ; 0 ; 3 ; 8 ; 0 ; 7
N.K.; 30 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 6 ; 2 ; 7 ''')

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=";", index_col='Operator')
days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri']
df[days] = df[days].astype(float)
```

```
### BEGIN SOLUTION
from pyomo.core.base.set_types import NonNegativeIntegers
def model_oxbridge():
  model = pyo.ConcreteModel('ProductionPlan')

  model.names = pyo.Set(initialize=df[days].index)
  names = ["K.C.", "D.H.", "H.B.", "S.C.", "K.S.", "N.K."]
  min_h = list(df["MinHours"])
  #print(names)
  model.days = pyo.Set(initialize=days)
  model.x = pyo.Var(model.names, days, domain=NonNegativeIntegers)
  model.wage = pyo.Objective(expr = pyo.quicksum([pyo.quicksum(df["Wage"][names.index(i)]*model.x[i, t] for t in days) for i in df[days].index]), sense=pyo.minimize)

  for i in df[days].index:
    model.min_hours = pyo.Constraint(expr = pyo.quicksum([model.x[i, t] for t in days]) >= min_h[names.index(i)])

  for i in df[days].index:
    for t in days:
      model.availability = pyo.Constraint(expr = model.x[i,t] <= df[days][t][i])
  
    for t in days:
      model.day_total = pyo.Constraint(expr = pyo.quicksum([model.x[i, t] for i in df[days].index]) == 14)

  return model
### END SOLUTION
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't contain a clear description of the problem. It merely contains an assertion that the code should return a different number than it does currently.